# Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service - installation sitecore 10

Tags: xconnect

I am trying to install sitecore 10 using garphic setup but i get error.
[image]

I checked the logs of xconnect-log-MarketingAutomation and i found the below error, also i sarched about the error and i did all recommanded solutions that i found and still the same. i cleared all sitecore certificate and started the installation again and getting same error. also i did the recommanded solutions in this link
[Getting Error - Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service - While installing Sitecore 9.2 via SIA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20728/getting-error-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-engine-service-while)

I tried to install it in other machine and it worked that means the certificate is valid so i need another ideas how can i solve this error.

> 2021-02-15 12:53:11.702 +04:00 [Error] Error initializing XConnect client.
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError
> at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.d__7.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.d__34.MoveNext()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.XConnect.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions.InitializeXConnectClientConfiguration(IServiceProvider provider, XConnectClientConfiguration config)
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError
> at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.d__7.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.d__34.MoveNext()<---

2021-02-15 12:53:11.750 +04:00 [Error] Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service.
System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.b__1(IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine()
at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.EngineService.OnStart(String[] args)

Comment: Probably most solutions are already included in this post https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en/27545#27545 . Can be the cert does not have enough permission for example. See my post in attached thread.

Comment: I also facing the same issue and have tried all of the below answers but I still having an issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while installing the Sitecore 10.X version on my local machine. I referred to the below similar question on StackExchange and followed the steps mentioned in the most-voted answer, and it started working for me.

[Sitecore 9.3 Installation failing - 'Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en)

Steps to resolve this issue

Run the below PS command

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}
```

If you get any response after running this command then run the below command

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

After running the above command reinitiate the Sitecore installation.

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with Sitecore 10.2 installation recently. I tried moving the certificates to root but that didn't resolve the issue for me. Enabling Asp.Net 3.5 under the Windows features fixed it for me.

[image]

Comment: I just recently faced the same issue.
Tried a lot of other possible solutions.
But in the end the server was just missing the ASP.NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors when trying to access the xconnect service url in the browser?

One other cause could be if you have any un-signed certificates on your machine. Execute below powershell command to check the un-signed certificates: `Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject}`

If there are any certificates on the list they need to be moved into the Intermediate Certification Authorities store. The below poweshell script helps to move them. `Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA`

Comment: yes, i get this error "This page isn’t working
sc10xconnect.dev.local is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500"

I tried this Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} and i do not have any unsigned certificate

Comment: I am getting the same error while installing Sitecore 10.2 on a Windows 11 machine. What is your OS version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install on Windows 11 then I would highly recommend executing the below steps:

```
New-Item -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
```

I recently encountered this myself when trying to install Sitecore 10.2 on Windows 11.

More details can be found here: https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/11/15/sitecore-running-sitecore-on-windows-11/