# Sitecore 10 Installation Error: Failed to Start Service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine' while an instance of 9.0.2 also running on my system

Tags: xconnect, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

Note: I have multiple Solr installed on my local environment one is for the previous version and now I have added Solr for Sitecore 10 on port 8984
So my Solr path for the Sitecore 10 is https://localhost:8984/solr/

I keep getting the same error and I have tried following steps to fix the issue with no luck

- we  have tried removing all the certificates except the certificate for solr
- we have tried uninstall and reinstall the iis
- Have enabled all the IIS features that are required

[image]

- Tried running the following script with no result

```
    Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$.Issuer -ne $.Subject}
```

- also tried the solution mentioned in the following links as well with no luck at all.
  [Sitecore 9.3 Installation failing - 'Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en)

[Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service - installation sitecore 10](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27643/failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-engine-service-installation-sitecore)

[Getting Error - Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service - While installing Sitecore 9.2 via SIA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20728/getting-error-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-engine-service-while)

**Updated:
After reading some comments I am updating the errors that are shown under the logs file on this location:** App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Logs

**Error1:**

```
Error initializing XConnect client.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

**Error2:**

```
Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service.
System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<UseServiceDecorator>b__1(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.EngineService.OnStart(String[] args)
```

Comment: Navigate to marketing automotion folder and open command prompt/powershell and try to run maengine.exe from it. It should give you more insights about error.

Comment: Path is app_data/jobs/continous/automotionengine . Might be you need different .net core version installed. Sitecore 9 needed version 2 and sitecore 10 requieres version 3. Please refer to official requirements.

Comment: @Kamil
I have updated my question with log's error details from the location you have mentioned

Comment: This was asked 10 months ago. Is it still an issue?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I resolved this issue by disabling TLS 1.3 over TCP.

Open PowerShell as an admin and run the below commands

> - New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
>   1.3\Server' -Force | Out-Null
> - New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
>   1.3\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
> - New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
>   1.3\Server'  -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

More detail you can find [here](https://swatiguptablogs.blogspot.com/2022/02/sitecore-102-failed-to-start-service.html)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issues while installing Sitecore 10.3 on Windows 11. I have run the above commands and restarted the installation but it failed again. Then I tried after enabling .NET 3.5 from the Windows feature and after that, it successfully installed the Sitecore instance.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting 2 possible solutions,

1. Try specifying the SOLR URL during installation as **https://localhost:8984/solr** instead of ending it with '/' at the end (i.e., https://localhost:8984/solr/)

This has helped me and my team resolve this issue in the past.

2. Check if this issue is due to **.NET target runtime** as described in the below blog. You can verify this by checking the logs in the Windows Event viewer as mentioned in the link.

https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2020/12/sitecore-10-sif-installation-failed-to.html

**Note :** To exactly identify the cause of your issue, you might need to gather additional information from the logs etc to be able to resolve it. So, try to see if you can gather some more info about this error - like checking the Event viewer logs etc

Comment: I have verified that .net framework 4.8 is already installed on my system. and also during installation I have used "https://localhost:8984/solr" path for solr and also I have update my question which contains log's error details